# Not able to run Force.com IDE on Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: force.com-ide

I have installed a fresh new eclipse on fresh new windows machine.

Eclipse version is eclipse-java-neon-3-win32-x86_64.

Installed a new Force.com IDE following by instructions from 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm

However, eclipse crashes after installation of Force.com IDE plugin with the following error in workspace/.metadata/.log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2018-04-02 11:44:41.801
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while creating new instance of component Component[
    name = AuraWorkspace
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = true
    implementation = mega.core.index.AuraWorkspace
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = null
    references = {
        Reference[name = IWorkspace, interface = org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setWorkspace, unbind = null]
        Reference[name = IWorkbench, interface = org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setWorkbench, unbind = null]
    }
    located in bundle = mega.lightning_2.0.0.201701101558 [492]
] 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3295)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareUIPlugin.start(CompareUIPlugin.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3295)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.loadHandler(HandlerProxy.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.setEnabled(HandlerProxy.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.canExecute(E4HandlerProxy.java:71)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.isEnabled(HandlerServiceHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.isEnabled(Command.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.registerLegacyHandler(LegacyHandlerService.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.registerLegacyHandler(LegacyHandlerService.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.readDefaultHandlers(LegacyHandlerService.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.readRegistry(LegacyHandlerService.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$49.runWithException(Workbench.java:2486)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4821)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(StartupThreading.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeDefaultServices(Workbench.java:2480)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2944)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$9(Workbench.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 95 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by switching to a JAVA 1.8 version. I was using a 1.10

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more context for a newbie? How did you effect the switch?

Comment: OK found some documentation on editing eclipse.ini to point to a diff version of java VM : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM